# ESLint: How to set "new-cap" rule's "capIsNewExceptions" option within a file?

Tags: javascript, eslint

Here is my attempt to set [ESLint's](http://eslint.org/) `new-cap` rule to accept `"S"` as an allowed function name:

```
/*eslint new-cap : [capIsNewExceptions : ["S"]] */
var S = require("string");
var lines = S(text).lines(); // <-- ESLint still gives a warning for cap 'S'!
```

My ESLint parser (within IntelliJ) continues to give me the `new-cap` warning, as noted.

I have tried to apply the [ESLint documentation](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring.html) carefully.

From [here](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring.html#configuring-rules), I see an example rule, which looks like this: `/*eslint quotes: [2, "double"], curly: 2*`/, in which I gather that the `quotes` and `curly` rules are being set, and that the `quotes` rule contains two options, which are therefore contained in brackets because the documentation says `If a rule has additional options, you can specify them using array literal syntax` (it says this right above the example).

Then, from [the actual documentation for `new-cap`](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/new-cap#capisnewexceptions), I find `capIsNewExceptions` is provided as an option, and that the value of this option should be an array of desired function names - just as I've tried to do in my code, above.

But it doesn't work.  I still receive the ESLint warning.

What is the correct syntax to support the use of customizing the `capIsNewExceptions` option for the `new-cap` rule inside a Javascript file for use with ESLint?

Comment: It's a nice rule -- why not follow it? When requiring things that you would `new`, use an uppercase. Otherwise, a lowercase (so for functions, objects, etc)?

Comment: @Cymen I think this is an eminently excellent exception, and the standard usage for the `Node` `String` library.  (See https://www.npmjs.com/package/string#node-js)

Comment: It's definitely subjective but I'd tend to use `string` for that library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
/*eslint new-cap: [2, {capIsNewExceptions: ["S"]}]*/
var S = require("string");
var lines = S(text).lines();
```

Now, why does it work this way?

You're right about passing options to the rule using array, but in [the docs](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring.html#configuring-rules) they mention that the first element of this array is always a “rule ID”: number from 0 to 2, that defines how that rule is applied:
  `0` — disables the rule,
  `1` — makes it a warning,
  `2` — makes it an error.

I'm too lazy to check, but I assume that the rest of the array is passed to the rule itself as an `options` property of the `context`. From the [source code](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/blob/master/lib/rules/new-cap.js#L69) of the `new-cap` rule, it looks like it expects only one option that is an object with possible configuration properties like `capIsNewExceptions`, `newIsCap`, etc.